Reference for Yosida Approximation
I am trying to understand Yosida approximation from "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces", but I am not able to fully understand the concept. Can someone suggest some beginner-level books to understand Yosida approximation?

For gaining intuition on monotone operators, I find it's always helpful to first try and look at the variational case -- i.e., when the monotone operator $A$ is the subdifferential (or gradient) of a convex, proper, lower-semicontinuous function $f\in\Gamma_0(\mathcal{H})$, in particular, $A=\partial f$.
Before we present an intuition for the Yosida approximation, let's take a brief detour to talk about the Moreau Envelope. This is a construction which has a bunch of nice properties and is used frequently across convex analysis. The concept is rigorously described in Section 12.4 of the book with some nice examples. One of the important properties of the Moreau Envelope is that, even if $f\in\Gamma_0(\mathcal{H})$ is nonsmooth, the Moreau envelope of $f$ is always differentiable; furthermore, the formula for the gradient of the Moreau Envelope of $f$ (with parameter $\gamma>0$) is $$\gamma^{-1}(\textrm{Id}-\textrm{prox}_{\gamma f}).$$
Now, let's look at Definition 23.1 of the Yosida approximation with parameter $\gamma>0$:
$$\gamma^{-1}(\textrm{Id}-J_{\gamma A}),$$
where $J_{\gamma A}$ is a resolvent. However, as you may already know, $J_{\gamma \partial f}=\textrm{prox}_{\gamma f}$: in words, the resolvent is the monotone-operator generalization of the prox.
With this in mind, if we compare Proposition 12.30 (in the same book) and Definition 23.1 of the Yosida approximation, we see that the Yosida approximation is basically just the monotone-operator generalization of the gradient of a Moreau envelope.
